# Splicing array and return elements not equal to specific elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object that is converted using `Object.keys()` where the keys are stored in array. I am trying to loop through the array to splice out keys that are not needed for the rest of my function that I am trying to write.

```
var objectDef = { 
    pitcher: 'dave',
    runner: 'joel',
    umpire: 'kevin',
    action/0/id: 1,
    action/0/name: 'review', 
    action/0/killjoy: 'no' 
  }

  //define array of keys
 var givenObject = typeof objecDef == "object" ? Object.keys(objectDef) : [objectDef];
```

How would I go about splicing out splicing action/0/killjoy and action/0/name? I only want pitcher, runner, umpire, and action/0/id returned. These unwanted fields may or may not exist depending on the data that is received from the server.

Comment: You could [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=example) them out.

Comment: Your last line `typeof == "object"` should be throwing a syntax error...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-to-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Sorry, it is a typo. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: It should be `typeof objectDef == "object"`.

Comment: @Demon `typeOf == "object"` might have been correct if `typeOf` was defined, but _now_ it’s definitely wrong, because `typeof` is missing its operand.

Comment: `action/0/name` is not a valid property name.

Comment: Okay. I corrected my error what I meant to say was use var givenObjects

Comment: Do you want to remove the unwanted property names from your array of property names, or to remove those properties and their values from the object?

Comment: I want to remove the unwanted property names in `givenObjects` because that is where I am trying to do other things with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Object.keys(objectDef).filter(key=>typeof objectDef[key]!=="object");
```

Simply check if that objects element is an object...

Comment: well I'm trying to use array to store the all the keys and remove  the last 2 elements from the arary so I can return the first 4 elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use [object spread/rest notation](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread):

```
const {'action/0/killjoy': ignore1, 'action/0/name': ignore2, ...newObject} = objectDef;
```

`newObject` will now contain the remaining properties.

You'll need some kind of transpiler for this until there is browser support.

Comment: Oh, I am using babel for transpiler

Comment: Then see https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/.